# Is there a way to build a ushahidi like website using WordPress or Drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, geo, crowdsourcing

I would like to know if there is some Drupal module or a WordPress plugin that enables the creation of a [ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/) type website (Ushahidi is a non-profit software company that develops free and open source software for information collection, visualization and interactive mapping.)

I am asking this to know if one can use the feautres that ushahidi is offering, while also leveraging all of the other plugins/modules created in these more mature platforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Managing News Drupal distribution](http://drupal.org/project/managingnews) might be helpful.